# jquery datatables + jeditable get data from ajax source for select list table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a jquery datatable populating from an ajax call initially. There are two columns in the datatable that need to be editable and on click in the individual table cells for these two specific columns I want to make ajax calls to get a select list to populate in the table cell.

some source ...

```
data      : function(value, settings) {
               $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url: JSON API call,
                    dataType:'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function(response, status, error){                                               
                         console.log(response);
                         return response;
                    },                    
               });                                              
           },
type       : 'select',
onblur     : 'submit',
tooltip    : 'Click to edit...',
placeholder: ''
```

Doing the above is throwing the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined

I do see the response data in the console:

sample response data:

```
Object {170: "170", 180: "180", 570: "570", 580: "580", 670: "670", 680: "680", 800: "800", 907: "907", 908: "908", "": ""}
```

I have tried the async: false to make the ajax call asynchronous with the same effect.

Any help on ideas on setting dynamic ajax data with jeditable will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.